# Calling different ng-bootstrap modal popup in Angular 6

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am following the tutorial for ng-bootstrap modal popup to add, edit, and delete within a grid. I added a ng-template to Add with the following button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openAdd(content)" >Add</button>
```

This will open a modal dialog with the following ng-template code

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{meetingDateTitle}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="meetingDate">Meeting Date:</label>
          <div class="input-group">
              <input id="meetingDate" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp1" #c2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="meetingRequest.MeetingDt" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
              <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="d1.toggle()" >  
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
              </div> 
          </div>
          <br/>

          <br/>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="saveAddMeeting">Save</button> -->
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" (click) ="saveMeeting()" >
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

My question, if I create another ng-template for the Delete confirmation, how do I call the different popup dialog window?

```
I see that the bootstrap call for another button is this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true});
```

which was used to call the Add popup. How do I make another modalService.open call to call the delete dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `content` that you passed in parameter to your function. This variable is declared in the template scope with `#content` and represent your `ng-template` element.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openAdd(content)" >Add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openAdd(delete)" >Delete</button>

<ng-template #content let-modal>
...
 </ng-template>

<ng-template #delete let-modal>
...
</ng-template>
```